# Window cmd not matching correct output

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to search all the countries available in a text file (country.txt) in 2000 XML file and if it is matching, then all those files should be moved to Valid_countryname folder and if mismatch, then it should move to invalid folder. 
I have created one batch file with below code but it is not working perfectly.
Requirement is country should match completely within XML file or based on wild card search (like operator).

```
findstr /m  /i  /g:country.txt ..\*.xml >country.txt
for /f %%f in (country.txt) do move %%f "..\Valid_countryname/"
```

Comment: Read your error messages. Congratulations, you overwrote your `country.txt` before `findstr` had a chance to process it.

Comment: I have no idea abut the script file. All countries list are available in text. Therefore, I think findstr command took first country name and search in all xml file and if it found, it moves to valid folder using loop approach. The program is working ifne but it compares only the first characters in xml file (not all characters) for which there is an inconsistency in moving wrong file into valid folder. Please check the program and guide. Thanks in advance

Comment: The batch file contain below code.   ECHO ON
::call mvn clean install
findstr /m  /i  /g:country.txt ..\*.xml >country.txt
::call mvn clean install
for /f %%f in (country.txt) do move %%f "..\Valid_countryname/"
message.bat

Comment: what I tried to tell you: using the same filename for `/g` in `findstr` *and* for output redirection is a bad idea. The very first thing that happens is the redirection, which will initialize the file, so `findstr` has nothing to compare with.

Comment: @Abraham, do not put that much code in your comment. If the code in your question changed then EDIT your question and delete the comment.